# How to reuse an existing variable to access it via a oncheck event on a checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code snippet listed below. I am building a checkbox input dynamically and would like to bind a function to its onclick. My problem is that I would like to have access to the **args** (in bold below) from the onclick, how would that be possible?

`function MultipleCheckboxesEditor(args) {
      var $input, $picker;
      var defaultValue;
      var scope = this;`

```
  this.init = function () {
      $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />");
      $input.width($(args.container).innerWidth() - 25);
      $input.appendTo(args.container);

      $picker = $("<div class='editor-multiplecheckboxes-picker' />").appendTo(args.container);
      $picker.append("<div class='editor-multiplecheckboxes-helper'></div>");

      $('.editor-multiplecheckboxes-helper').append(
          args.column.editor.choices.map(function (value) {
              return '<div><input type="checkbox" value="{0}" onclick="refreshMulticheck(this)"{1}>{0}</input><div>'.f(
                  value,
                  jQuery.inArray(value, args.item[args.column.field].split(',')) >= 0 ? 'checked="checked"' : '');
          })
      );
```

As you can see, there is an checkbox created, but in the `refreshMulticheck` function currently, I can only access to the checkbox via the `this` variable...

How should I go in order to get access to the original **args** variable?
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're looking for `bind` see: [jQuery.bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [underscore.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

Comment: This looks like it! :) I am doing some tests with it to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding this

```
onclick="refreshMulticheck(this)"
```

to each checkbox, you can do something like this:

```
$('.editor-multiplecheckboxes-helper').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (event) {
    // do something
});
```